# Gradient / Opacity workaround

Tags: javascript, css, gradient

I have this situation now: [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/kcrvhkgy/)

I want to achieve this effect but I want the text to be selectable behind the gradient and the text to be scrollable even if I place the mouse over it.

Is there any workaround maybe playing with a javascript that chenges the opacity of the text on scrolling?

```
.gradient {
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,1) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%);
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,1) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%);
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0,0,0,1) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#000000', endColorstr='#00000000',GradientType=0 );
...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply set the [`pointer-events` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) of your `.gradient` element to `none`, like so:

```css
*{box-sizing:border-box;color:#fff;font-family:sans-serif;font-size:16px;margin:0;padding:0;}
#main{
    background:#000;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    overflow:auto;
    position:fixed;
    right:0;
    top:0;
}
.text {
    line-height:1.25em;
    padding:50vh 20px 0;
}
.gradient {
    background:linear-gradient(180deg,rgba(0,0,0,1),rgba(0,0,0,0));
    bottom:50vh;
    left:0;
    pointer-events:none;
    position:fixed;
    right:0;
    top:0;
}
.text>p{margin:0 0 20px;}
```

```html
<div id=main>
  <div class=gradient></div>
  <div class=text><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla quis bibendum lorem, vel pellentesque nibh. Fusce sollicitudin est nec pharetra lacinia. Fusce ultrices lectus ex, nec pharetra dolor malesuada at. Aenean sagittis, enim non sagittis accumsan, libero nulla ullamcorper nunc, sit amet dapibus orci ligula gravida leo. Suspendisse molestie eros diam, volutpat tincidunt libero faucibus at. Sed condimentum tortor tincidunt tortor accumsan pulvinar. Sed at bibendum lorem, euismod tempor urna. Vivamus quis erat dolor. Maecenas sed nisl luctus, tempor mauris suscipit, porta nisl. Nam ac nulla condimentum, posuere nisl sit amet, tincidunt ante. Sed vestibulum, orci in imperdiet malesuada, ex dolor accumsan tellus, at auctor purus sapien at lacus. Nullam ullamcorper justo ac malesuada blandit. Fusce pretium et massa id eleifend. Cras quis dapibus tellus.</p><p>Curabitur et eros id risus sodales fringilla. Cras iaculis efficitur mi non accumsan. Sed congue ligula ut ligula semper egestas. Duis varius dolor ex, eu tempor nunc auctor ut. In ultricies malesuada eros, sed dictum justo auctor nec. Nunc blandit finibus ligula vel hendrerit. Fusce id blandit ante, sed euismod turpis. Phasellus elit lorem, eleifend ut facilisis non, tincidunt varius arcu. Duis gravida varius quam, vestibulum eleifend nisi volutpat a. In tempus velit justo, a auctor felis congue ac. Praesent dapibus vestibulum ex, a tincidunt justo interdum vel. Integer neque tortor, aliquam vitae quam at, hendrerit ullamcorper tellus. Suspendisse pharetra rutrum nunc vitae tristique. Aenean id ipsum purus. Nunc interdum id odio vel consectetur. Praesent convallis iaculis dolor eu pretium.</p><p>Aenean tincidunt urna vitae euismod vulputate. Integer tincidunt dolor sit amet ligula vehicula aliquet. Aliquam erat volutpat. Vivamus id lorem leo. Fusce faucibus, nisl non malesuada mollis, felis elit aliquam lacus, et ullamcorper lectus felis a eros. Quisque a nulla justo. Phasellus vitae purus viverra, mattis odio vitae, vehicula tellus. Nam eget vehicula velit, sed fermentum arcu. Proin laoreet molestie purus non laoreet. Nunc quis luctus lorem. Sed sit amet sapien quis eros pellentesque vestibulum. Pellentesque semper libero turpis, ac mattis orci tempus quis. Cras nunc nisi, accumsan sed dictum in, condimentum et tortor. Etiam tincidunt eget ex id ultrices. Ut lobortis faucibus porttitor. Mauris nisi est, tincidunt in sagittis eu, fermentum ac purus.</p><p>Phasellus fringilla sodales vehicula. Nam id diam convallis, interdum nisi non, tincidunt felis. Vestibulum efficitur mollis porttitor. Sed vehicula urna eget neque maximus, eget fringilla augue sollicitudin. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Curabitur elementum suscipit neque, id lacinia tortor sagittis non. Aenean placerat velit nec tellus mattis, quis lobortis erat vulputate. Donec in ligula fermentum, ornare augue nec, scelerisque leo. Proin nec odio lobortis purus pharetra sodales. Suspendisse finibus ligula in mi venenatis, et lacinia augue euismod. In aliquam velit ac mi laoreet faucibus. Nunc a volutpat ex. Mauris odio velit, efficitur et tortor nec, vulputate hendrerit mauris.</p><p>Morbi vel placerat sapien. Nunc vitae nunc sed magna tincidunt convallis id sit amet dui. Nam diam massa, suscipit et urna eu, egestas accumsan dui. Praesent sagittis dui auctor felis ultrices venenatis. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Maecenas vitae pharetra leo. Nullam feugiat vestibulum nisi, sit amet tempor purus molestie eget. Aliquam et nisi sit amet purus tempus sollicitudin bibendum ultricies eros. Integer cursus fermentum diam, eget lacinia magna ultrices at. Ut venenatis massa sem.</p></div>
</div>
```

However, you could achieve the same result with a little less markup by using a [pseudo-element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements) to create your gradient:

```css
*{box-sizing:border-box;color:#fff;font-family:sans-serif;font-size:16px;margin:0;padding:0;}
div{
    background:#000;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    line-height:1.25em;
    overflow:auto;
    padding:50vh 20px 0;
    position:fixed;
    right:0;
    top:0;
}
div::after{
    background:linear-gradient(180deg,rgba(0,0,0,1),rgba(0,0,0,0));
    bottom:50vh;
    content:"";
    left:0;
    pointer-events:none;
    position:fixed;
    right:0;
    top:0;
}
.text>p{margin:0 0 20px;}
```

```html
<div><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla quis bibendum lorem, vel pellentesque nibh. Fusce sollicitudin est nec pharetra lacinia. Fusce ultrices lectus ex, nec pharetra dolor malesuada at. Aenean sagittis, enim non sagittis accumsan, libero nulla ullamcorper nunc, sit amet dapibus orci ligula gravida leo. Suspendisse molestie eros diam, volutpat tincidunt libero faucibus at. Sed condimentum tortor tincidunt tortor accumsan pulvinar. Sed at bibendum lorem, euismod tempor urna. Vivamus quis erat dolor. Maecenas sed nisl luctus, tempor mauris suscipit, porta nisl. Nam ac nulla condimentum, posuere nisl sit amet, tincidunt ante. Sed vestibulum, orci in imperdiet malesuada, ex dolor accumsan tellus, at auctor purus sapien at lacus. Nullam ullamcorper justo ac malesuada blandit. Fusce pretium et massa id eleifend. Cras quis dapibus tellus.</p><p>Curabitur et eros id risus sodales fringilla. Cras iaculis efficitur mi non accumsan. Sed congue ligula ut ligula semper egestas. Duis varius dolor ex, eu tempor nunc auctor ut. In ultricies malesuada eros, sed dictum justo auctor nec. Nunc blandit finibus ligula vel hendrerit. Fusce id blandit ante, sed euismod turpis. Phasellus elit lorem, eleifend ut facilisis non, tincidunt varius arcu. Duis gravida varius quam, vestibulum eleifend nisi volutpat a. In tempus velit justo, a auctor felis congue ac. Praesent dapibus vestibulum ex, a tincidunt justo interdum vel. Integer neque tortor, aliquam vitae quam at, hendrerit ullamcorper tellus. Suspendisse pharetra rutrum nunc vitae tristique. Aenean id ipsum purus. Nunc interdum id odio vel consectetur. Praesent convallis iaculis dolor eu pretium.</p><p>Aenean tincidunt urna vitae euismod vulputate. Integer tincidunt dolor sit amet ligula vehicula aliquet. Aliquam erat volutpat. Vivamus id lorem leo. Fusce faucibus, nisl non malesuada mollis, felis elit aliquam lacus, et ullamcorper lectus felis a eros. Quisque a nulla justo. Phasellus vitae purus viverra, mattis odio vitae, vehicula tellus. Nam eget vehicula velit, sed fermentum arcu. Proin laoreet molestie purus non laoreet. Nunc quis luctus lorem. Sed sit amet sapien quis eros pellentesque vestibulum. Pellentesque semper libero turpis, ac mattis orci tempus quis. Cras nunc nisi, accumsan sed dictum in, condimentum et tortor. Etiam tincidunt eget ex id ultrices. Ut lobortis faucibus porttitor. Mauris nisi est, tincidunt in sagittis eu, fermentum ac purus.</p><p>Phasellus fringilla sodales vehicula. Nam id diam convallis, interdum nisi non, tincidunt felis. Vestibulum efficitur mollis porttitor. Sed vehicula urna eget neque maximus, eget fringilla augue sollicitudin. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Curabitur elementum suscipit neque, id lacinia tortor sagittis non. Aenean placerat velit nec tellus mattis, quis lobortis erat vulputate. Donec in ligula fermentum, ornare augue nec, scelerisque leo. Proin nec odio lobortis purus pharetra sodales. Suspendisse finibus ligula in mi venenatis, et lacinia augue euismod. In aliquam velit ac mi laoreet faucibus. Nunc a volutpat ex. Mauris odio velit, efficitur et tortor nec, vulputate hendrerit mauris.</p><p>Morbi vel placerat sapien. Nunc vitae nunc sed magna tincidunt convallis id sit amet dui. Nam diam massa, suscipit et urna eu, egestas accumsan dui. Praesent sagittis dui auctor felis ultrices venenatis. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Maecenas vitae pharetra leo. Nullam feugiat vestibulum nisi, sit amet tempor purus molestie eget. Aliquam et nisi sit amet purus tempus sollicitudin bibendum ultricies eros. Integer cursus fermentum diam, eget lacinia magna ultrices at. Ut venenatis massa sem.</p></div>
```

Answer (score -2):

You may try using:

```
html {
    overflow: overlay;
}
```

at the end of your .CSS file

Comment: `overlay` is not a valid value for the `overflow` property.

Comment: Yes it is @Shaggy. But it's non-standard and only applies to WebKit.
I didn't know that before trying to answer (and therefore lose reputation points for the first time ever).
Maybe you can check it out in [here](http://w3-org.9356.n7.nabble.com/css3-ui-Proposal-for-an-quot-overlay-quot-value-for-overflow-td244662.html)

Comment: Sorry Federico Ferrari, I think I misunderstood the question.
The answer by @Shaggy is right to the point.